# xpath - how can I select the checkbox based on the text before it

Tags: xpath

I have text that says 'Roles'.  After that there are two checkboxes.
I can get to 'Roles'.
How can I get to and click check the checkboxes?

I am trying to use:

```
xpath=(//label[contains(text(),'Roles')]/div/span/input)
```

but getting not found.

My HTML is:

```
<div class="control-group string required">
  <label class="string required control-label" for="survey_name">
  <abbr title="required">*</abbr> Name</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input class="string required" id="survey_name" name="survey[name]" size="50" type="text" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group check_boxes required">
    <label class="check_boxes required control-label">
      <abbr title="required">*</abbr> Roles
    </label>
    <div class="controls">
      <span class="checkbox">
        <input class="check_boxes required" id="survey_role_ids_121" name="survey[role_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="121" />
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `div` is not a child of the label, is is a `following-sibling`. Therefore, the XPath expression you need is

```
//label[contains(., "Roles")]/following-sibling::div/span/input
```